# How to convert nested list name into tibble with row names

Tags: r, dataframe, tidyverse

I have the following nested list:

```
l <- list(`1` = c(Fn1 = 85.3820037423659, Sema3c = 0.0362596376899117, 
App = 8.08423415658745), `3` = c(Fn1 = 11.0051859200698, Sema3c = 0, 
App = 44.0000000000306), `4` = c(Fn1 = 3.4594316186373, Sema3c = 0, 
App = 6.54280428377643))
```

That looks like this:

```
$`1`
        Fn1      Sema3c         App 
85.38200374  0.03625964  8.08423416 

$`3`
     Fn1   Sema3c      App 
11.00519  0.00000 44.00000 

$`4`
     Fn1   Sema3c      App 
3.459432 0.000000 6.542804
```

What I want to convert them into tibble.

```
               `1`   `3`   `4`

  Fn1      85.4     11.0  3.46
  Semac3    0.0363   0    0   
  App      8.08    44.   6.54
```

How can I achieve that?

I tried `tibble::as_tibble(l)` but it doesn't show the row name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is one way with `tidyverse`. Since we have a numeric vector in the list we first convert it into a tibble, combine the list of tibbles into one dataframe using `bind_rows`, get the data in long format, bring it back to wide format changing the column names and turn the `name` column to rownames.

```
library(tidyverse)

map(l, ~as_tibble(t(.x))) %>%
    bind_rows(.id = 'id') %>%
    pivot_longer(cols = -id) %>%
    pivot_wider(names_from = id, values_from = value) %>%
    column_to_rownames('name')

#             1  3    4
#Fn1    85.3820 11 3.46
#Sema3c  0.0363  0 0.00
#App     8.0842 44 6.54
```

Comment: Wouldn't just `data.frame(l, check.names=FALSE)` work, or am I missing some complexity here? A `data.frame` is just a `list` under the hood anyway.

Comment: @thelatemail Oops..**facepalm**. You are right, the fact that `l` is a list of vector confused me. You should add that as an answer.

Comment: @Onyambu - without it I get `X1, X3, X4` as the names.

Answer (score 1):

We can use `unnest_wider`

```
library(tidyr)
library(purrr)
tibble(col1 = map(l, as.list)) %>% 
       unnest_wider(col1) %>% 
       t
```

---

Or using `transpose` from `purrr` and `map`

```
library(tibble)
transpose(l) %>% 
    map_df(~ .x, .id = 'grp') %>%
    column_to_rownames('grp')
#               1        3        4
#Fn1    85.38200374 11.00519 3.459432
#Sema3c  0.03625964  0.00000 0.000000
#App     8.08423416 44.00000 6.542804
```